# Swift: Looking for calling an API with Alamofire within a loop

Tags: ios, swift, rest, alamofire

I need to call an Web API(web service) multiple time with different parameters available in an array. Trying to call API within getting a loop and use Alamofire. It responds properly for initial 3-4 calling. After that it move to failed state.

API call in not interdependent. Appreciated any example.

Comment: Add your code snippet for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use Dispatch Groups:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    longRunningFunction { dispatchGroup.leave() }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    longRunningFunctionTwo { dispatchGroup.leave() }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("Both functions complete ")
    }
```

The before code, it's a little example, you can try using similar concepts, insert your function within the loop for example and implement .leave() on each iteration